# Active all data id and # when Onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Problem going wrong is when i **Onclick for "c-1" btn in div=mark-container,** the same id will be active in the same time,but the another button which also is **"c-1" in the div = second-mark** , wouldn't active together,how to make" it to be active together?

```js
$('.c-1').click(function() {
  var tab = $(this).attr('data-id');

  $('.c-1').removeClass('active');
  $(".c-1-details").removeClass('active');

  $(this).addClass('active');
  $("[id='" + tab + "']").addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.c-1-details {
  display: none;
}

.c-1-details.active {
  display: block;
}

.active {
  color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="mark-container">
  <button class="c-1 active" data-id="tab-1">
       <p>for 1 btn</p> 
      </button>

  <button class="c-1" data-id="tab-2">
       <p>for 2 btn</p>
      </button>

  <div class="c-1-details active" id="tab-1">
    <p>for 1 details</p>
  </div>

  <div class="c-1-details" id="tab-2">
    <p>for 2 details</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="second-mark">
  <ul>
    <button class="c-1 active" data-id="tab-1">current btn 1</button>

    <button class="c-1" data-id="tab-2">current btn2</button>
  </ul>

  <div class="c-1-details active" id="tab-1">
    display content 1
  </div>

  <div class="c-1-details" id="tab-2">
    display content 2
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `id` must be unique in an html page... Why can't you use `data-id` for them as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments `id` should be unique to an element. Common elements can always be indicated with same `class`. The code below is self-explanatory.

```js
$('.c-1').click(function() {
            var tab = $(this).attr('data-id');
            $('.c-1,.c-1-details').removeClass('active');
            $('.' + tab + ', .details-' + tab).addClass('active');
        });
```

```css
.c-1-details {
        display: none;
    }

    .c-1-details.active {
        display: block;
    }

    .active {
        color: green;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    


      <div class="mark-container">
        <button class="c-1 tab-1 active" data-id="tab-1">
            <p>for 1 btn</p> 
        </button>

        <button class="c-1 tab-2" data-id="tab-2">
            <p>for 2 btn</p>
        </button>

        <div class="c-1-details details-tab-1 active" data-id="tab-1">
            <p>for 1 details</p>
        </div>

        <div class="c-1-details details-tab-2" data-id="tab-2">
            <p>for 2 details</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="second-mark">
        <ul>
            <button class="c-1 tab-1 active" data-id="tab-1">current btn 1</button>

            <button class="c-1 tab-2" data-id="tab-2">current btn2</button>
        </ul>

        <div class="c-1-details details-tab-1 active" data-id="tab-1">
            display content 1
        </div>

        <div class="c-1-details details-tab-2 " data-id="tab-2">
            display content 2
        </div>
    </div>
```